# White square printed when proof from asmthm is used

Tags: packages

I have a problem, because when I use proof from asmthm, then   a white square is displayed in the proof. Is there a possibility to remove it?

Example.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to place `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` in your preamble, if you want to omit the end-of-proof symbol in general.

Comment: You might find it useful to read the `amsthm` documentation -- `texdoc amsthdoc`.

Comment: The symbol is also known as the tombstone, and has been a tradition in math books for a very long time in order to let people know that the proof has ended.

Comment: Thank all of you. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! This white square is a symbol to denote the end of the proof (similar to the three letters Q.E.D. or a black square). The [documentation for the `amsthm` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) tells us that you can use `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` in the preamble of your document to omit the Q.E.D. symbol in general (or to change it so some other symbol):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One may also use  Ο.E.Δ. …

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly what I was looking for.